# Why the value of this portfolio is negative?

Tags: options, option-pricing

Let's assume

- I buy 1 call with strike 100 and 1 call with strike 120
- I sell 2 calls with strike 110

(with same expiration)

I wonder why value of this portfolio is negative at $t=0$?

Comment: I'm down voting this question. The OP keeps on changing the question, and most importantly, seems like he's quite confused with basics of option pricing, both on terminology and technique.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check them individually and understand how option pricing works. 
Then you will realize that you want to sell 2 put options *Deeply in the money*(cheap to buy), buy one call option *At the money* (a bit expensive) and finally buy an "Out of the money" call option (cheap). 
So you are trying to finance something a bit expensive by selling something cheap, therefore you need to add some of your cash. 
That is why it is negative.

Try to draw, and use numeric examples to understand it.

Comment: how do u know first option is deeply in the money etc?

Comment: Sorry, I missread it. You said 2 calls at 110. Therefore, you will be paying a lot for the 100 call because there is 50% chances of executing, and pay a bit for the 120. And you will recieve a lot less for both 110 call options.

Comment: But can you say that without knowing current price of underlying?

Comment: Usually when you are setting those values, you mean that 100 is the spot price of the underlying.

Answer (score -1):

This portfolio clearly doesn't have value of $0$ at $t = 0$. Ignoring the fact that you seem to have confused payoffs of option strategies and the value of a portfolio of options, even the payoffs themselves as given here will have state where the payoff is nonzero (i.e. $S_T \in [100,110]$). This by itself ensures that no matter what model you use for asset prices, you'll enjoy a nonnegative value to this portfolio at $t = 0$.

Comment: but let's say i'm selling a call. what is the value of my portfolio at $t=0$?

Comment: What do you mean by "but let's say i'm selling a call" here? Are you modifying the question? Beyond that, without knowing something about the asset pricing process, how can one have any hope of computing the $t = 0$ value of any single option, let alone this type of option strategy with multiple options, and where there are clearly states with a nonzero payoff?

Comment: Yes i'm modyfing my question. Assume my portfolio consists of one shorted call valued at 5$. What is value of my position?

Comment: Then you should edit the question, this confusion doesn't help anyone, including yourself.